# Editing the package name of an existing firebase project

Tags: android, firebase

I'm new to android development and sorry if I am asking a dumb question,  Are there any possible way to edit the package name of an existing fire-base project and get a new "google-services.json" file?
 [(image-> fire-base app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09vYQ.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's not possible,
you can delete your Application with the wrong package name and create a new one with the name you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but it's not possible, but you delete your App with the wrong package name and create a new one in the same projekt.

The package name is a static indetifier, if you upload your App to Google Play, then you can't change it either.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I know my answer is no good news for you, but if your questions is answered pls mark it as answered. You can do this by ckecking below the like/dislike Button :)